# c# printing an array list which is made of generic lists

Tags: c#, class, arraylist, generic-list

There is an array list, it is made of generic lists and generic lists' elements are class variables. How can i print the whole arrayList? I have to use array list, generic lists and a class. Logic is something like Array List[Generic Lists[Classes]].

````
namespace temp
{
    internal class tempClass
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Number;
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] Names =  { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m","n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u","v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "z2", "z3" };
            int[] Number = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 };
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
            int counter = 0;
            List<tempClass> genericList;
            tempClass ClassExample;
            for (int i = 0; i < Names.Length;)
            {
                genericList = new List<tempClass>();
                int elementCount = (int)Math.Pow(2, counter);
                for (int j = 0; j < elementCount; j++)
                {
                    ClassExample = new tempClass();
                    ClassExample.Name = Names[i];
                    ClassExample.Number = Number[i];
                    genericList.Add(ClassExample);
                    i++;
                    if (i == Names.Length) break;
                }
                arrayList.Add(genericList);
                counter++;
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: FYI `ArrayList` is a left over from .Net 1 before generics where added.  I'd suggest not using it at all and instead use `List<List<tempClass>>`.  Basically if you want to get at the stuff in an `ArrayList` you need to know the type and you can do `foreach(List<tempClass> x in arrayList)` however you can add anything to an `ArrayList` so it's possible to run into casting errors, which is why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: There is no reason at all to use an ArrayList. Also, what exactly do you need to print? It's just a simple loop within a main loop.

Comment: Please note the text in the blue box under the "Remarks" section of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0) for `ArrayList`: *"We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class."*

Comment: `List<tempClass> tempClasses = Enumerable.Range(0, Names.Length).Select(index => new tempClass {Name = Names[index], Number = Number[index]}).ToList();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below will give you a single dimensional list you can use foreach to print out each item.

```
List<tempClass> tests = arrayList.ToArray()
                               .Select(obj => (List<tempClass>)obj)
                               .Aggregate((first, second) => { second.AddRange(first.ToArray()); return second; });

foreach(tempClass test in tests)
{
   Console.WriteLine(test.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this and it worked, thanks!

```
            int counter2 = 0;
            foreach (List<tempClass> temp in arrayList)
            {
                foreach (tempClass temp2 in temp)
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + temp2.Name + " Number: " + temp2.Number);
            }
```